# Как правильно реализовать выезжающий бэкграунд у картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Как реализовать то, что на картинке правильно? Попробовал сделать псевдоэлементом - не получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Судя из вопроса нужен выезжающий (т.е анимация) фон у изображения. В тегах указан js, но автор не предоставил исходного кода. Мы можем писать без него.

Выезжающий, т.е совершающий действие. Окей, используем `keyframes`.

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 11px 12px 2px 5px #FF577E;
  animation: slide;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FF577E;
  }
  
  to {
    box-shadow: 11px 12px 2px 5px #FF577E;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
```

Для того чтобы создать фон у элемента вы сможете воспользоваться [генератор теней](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/).

А если вам анимация не нужна, то вы сможете добавить стиль тени в классу или тегу изображения. Вот так.

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 11px 12px 2px 5px #FF577E;
}
```

```html
<img class='img' src="http://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, но почти наверняка он хотел на hover. Ещё у теней так себе производительность, а градиентную тень нормально сделать вообще не получится.

Answer (score 0):

img является replaced-элементом, поэтому к нему самому псевдоэлементы приделывать нельзя, только к контейнеру. Вот вариант с оборачиванием в спан:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 16px - 1em);
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, purple, crimson, purple);
  transform: translate(0);
  transition: transform .3s linear;
}

span:hover::before {
  transform: translate(-1em, 1em);
}
```

```html
<span>
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/qykLA.png">
</span>
```